# Get third level xml data using php

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Hello I would like to get access to  some data in a xml using xpath but I don't know how to achieve it, The aim is to get the result like this:

1245, 00185, 10, new york
1245, 00185, 5, london
1246, 00186, 10, madrid
1246, 00186, 5, paris
1246, 00186, 8, munich

The xml is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<result>
<registry code="1245">
<PR_COD>00185</PR_COD>
<PR_DRE ncols="2">
  <row>
    <column_1>10</column>
    <column_2>new york</column>
  </row>
  <row>
    <column_1>5</column>
    <column_2>london</column>
  </row>
</PR_DRE>
</registry>
<registry code="1246">
<PR_COD>00186</PR_COD>
<PR_DRE ncols="3">
  <row>
    <column_1>10</column>
    <column_2>madrid</column>
  </row>
  <row>
    <column_1>5</column>
    <column_2>paris</column>
  </row>
  <row>
    <column_1>8</column>
    <column_2>munich</column>
  </row>
</PR_DRE>
</registry>
</result>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know [DOMXpath:evaluate()](http://php.net/domxpath)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to parse XML document:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
$result = $xml->xpath('.//PR_DRE/row/*');
```

or

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('file.xml', null, true);
$result = $xml->xpath('.//*/*/*');
```

Comment: Hi I have get the wished result using a foreach inside the main foreach calling to the parent node. Thank you
 foreach ( $cities->xpath('/*/*') as $cod)
 {
 $pr_cod =  $cod->PR_COD; 
}

Comment: But I have a problem now, I m always receiving the last value of the all parent nodes instead the  value of each element

Comment: @FranRod, еach element has one parent, so you can get parrents and then get all childs for them.

Comment: would you mind to show me how to do it ? I m trying and I only get the the first children value of each  parent

Comment: hi, I have already achieved what I want, i got the reference from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238878/xml-with-varying-amount-of-child-nodes-for-each-parent-node Thanks for everyone who helped me.

Comment: @FranRod, good job.